# Ruby on Rails first app not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am going through this tutorial: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
One thing I will mention is that I think I am using a different version of Rails to the tutorial. I am using version 2.3.14 
I am working on a Linux system. I set up a rails project thus:

```
rails myproject
```

WHich set up lots of directories and files as the tutorial said (although the tutorial uses slightly different commands)

Next, I set up my first app by creating a COntroller and View as follows:

```
ruby script/generate controller welcome index
```

This created files int he app directory of my project, in the controllers and views subdirectories. Namely, I know have the file index.html.erb in the views directory.

Next I just wanted to test the server:

```
ruby script/server
```

And then in my browser went to localhost:3000, which took me to the index.html file in the public directory.

This is where things go wrong. I want to be directed to the index.html.erb file in the views subdirectory. So, I went to config and opened the routes.rb file for editing. The following is my edited file:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   map.connect 'products/:id', :controller => 'catalog', :action => 'view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   map.purchase 'products/:id/purchase', :controller => 'catalog', :action => 'purchase'
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   map.resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   map.resources :products, :member => { :short => :get, :toggle => :post }, :collection => { :sold => :get }

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   map.resources :products, :has_many => [ :comments, :sales ], :has_one => :seller

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   map.resources :products do |products|
  #     products.resources :comments
  #     products.resources :sales, :collection => { :recent => :get }
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     admin.resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with map.root -- just remember to delete public/index.html.
   map.root :controller => "welcome#index"#I CHANGED THIS LINE

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # Install the default routes as the lowest priority.
  # Note: These default routes make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests. You should
  # consider removing or commenting them out if you're using named routes and resources.
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

I only made one change in the file. All I did was uncomment the line

```
map.root :controller => "welcome#index"
```

And point it to my index.html.erb file (at least that is what I think I am doing).
Restarting the server still sends me to index.html (in public directory). So I deleted the file. Killed the server, restarted. Now I get an error message. I cannot read my index.html.erb file. I would like any help in fixing this.

Comment: You are using Rails v2.3.x but using an edge guide (v3.2+). You're a whole major version behind. There are incompatibilities between the two. Upgrade or use the [v2.3 guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/).

Comment: Post the error message verbatim, please.

Comment: as @gg_s said, post your error message, that way we could help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some major differences in rails 2.x and rails 3.x.  If you are following the edgerails tutorial, then that is 3.x.  [Install the new version of rails](http://rubyonrails.org/download).  You should then have no trouble following the examples in the tutorial.

Edit: In fact, the installation instructions are in the tutorial itself.  If you are having trouble installing ruby 1.9, I rather like [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) for managing ruby versions.  [RVM](https://rvm.io/) is perhaps the more popular tool for this.

Comment: You were correct. After upgrading rails all is well in the world.

Answer (score 2):

Try this version of the Rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/

However, I would strongly recommend working with a more recent version of Rails (currently ~3.2) to start learning. It's likely to save you some time and effort.